# MSVC ifstream performance issue with unsigned datatype

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

I made some tests with `std::ifstream` on MSVC, when reading binary files. I have big performance differences between `char` and `unsigned char` data types.

Results when reading a 512 MB binary file:

```
Duration read as signed: 322 ms
Duration read as unsigned: 10552 ms
```

Below the code I used to test:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    const std::filesystem::path filePath{ "test.data" }; // 512 MB binary file
    const size_t fileSize{ std::filesystem::file_size(filePath) };

    {
        std::basic_ifstream<char> fileStream{ filePath, std::fstream::binary };
        std::vector<char> data;
        data.resize(fileSize);

        const auto start{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
        fileStream.read(data.data(), fileSize);
        const auto end{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };

        std::cout << "Duration read as signed: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char> fileStream{ filePath, std::fstream::binary };
        std::vector<unsigned char> data;
        data.resize(fileSize);

        const auto start{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
        fileStream.read(data.data(), fileSize);
        const auto end{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };

        std::cout << "Duration read as unsigned: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how using a `basic_ifstream<unsigned char>` is 30 times slower than `basic_ifstream<char>` when reading a binary file.

Comment: I was all ready to call you crazy, because this sounds crazy, but then I tried it. My file is ~550mb and I get ~500ms for the first and ~15,000ms for the second. Very strange.

Comment: I know it's very strange and unintuitive...

Comment: Standard streams simply aren't designed to handle `unsigned` types. In many environments, they won't even compile if you try to use `unsigned char` since things like `std::char_traits` aren't specialized for `unsigned char`. But clearly MSVC does implement specializations for `unsigned char` in this example, though maybe they are not optimal specializations. I'm guessing they are having to do extra data conversions internally, that could account for the extra time.

Comment: In this situation, I would suggest simply using the standard `std::ifstream` as-is. You can use a `std::vector<unsigned char>`, just type-cast to `char*` when calling `read()`, eg: `std::ifstream fileStream{ filePath, std::ifstream::binary }; std::vector<unsigned char> data(fileSize); fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), fileSize);`

Comment: And if you're really curious step into the two code paths.

Comment: Been awhile since I saw a head-scratcher on this site. Thanks, James!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance issue disappears when you set a read buffer like this :

```
    {
        std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char> fileStream{ filePath, std::fstream::binary };
        std::vector<unsigned char> data;
        data.resize(fileSize);

        unsigned char buf[8192U];
        fileStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 8192U);

        const auto start{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
        fileStream.read(data.data(), fileSize);
        const auto end{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };

        std::cout << "Duration read unsigned with buffer: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
```

Results:

```
Duration read signed: 331 ms
Duration read unsigned: 10505 ms
Duration read unsigned with buffer: 223 ms
```

Answer (score 5):

I've tracked this down to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\fstream` file, line 549:

```
virtual streamsize __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL xsgetn(_Elem* _Ptr, streamsize _Count) override {
    // get _Count characters from stream
    if constexpr (sizeof(_Elem) == 1) {
        if (_Count <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (_Pcvt) { // if we need a nontrivial codecvt transform, do the default expensive thing
            return _Mysb::xsgetn(_Ptr, _Count);
        }
```

For the `unsigned char` it goes into that `default expensive thing`

Looking a bit farther, I see this:

```
virtual streamsize __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL xsgetn(_Elem* _Ptr, streamsize _Count) { // get _Count characters from stream
    const streamsize _Start_count = _Count;

    while (0 < _Count) {
        streamsize _Size = _Gnavail();
        if (0 < _Size) { // copy from read buffer
            if (_Count < _Size) {
                _Size = _Count;
            }

            _Traits::copy(_Ptr, gptr(), static_cast<size_t>(_Size));
            _Ptr += _Size;
            _Count -= _Size;
            gbump(static_cast<int>(_Size));
        } else {
            const int_type _Meta = uflow();
            if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta)) {
                break; // end of file, quit
            }

            // get a single character
            *_Ptr++ = _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta);
            --_Count;
        }
    }

    return _Start_count - _Count;
}
```

Note one-by-one processing! And that function doesn't do much:

```
_NODISCARD static constexpr _Elem to_char_type(const int_type& _Meta) noexcept {
    return static_cast<_Elem>(_Meta);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found this too. The expensive path is just brutal.

Comment: But why do they do locale conversion with a file opened in binary mode ?

Comment: @JamesMagnus probably just a bug. You should report that on https://github.com/microsoft/STL/